# How to remove an entire string after multiple occurrences of certain characters?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to print the entire string which followed by "$" and remove all the other characters and strings.

Tried using sed command:

```
INPUT: FINDER=$FILE/$read\ammy.my

echo "$FINDER" | sed -r "s|[^a-zA-Z$]| |g"
```

Used this code

Result received from the above code:`$FILE $read ammy my`

Expected result:`$FILE $read`

Comment: I've read your question 3 times, I still cannot understand your requirement... what do you think the English word "WHATEVER" mean?

Comment: You've written your requirements in terms of double negatives (consider `remove X except Y` vs `print Y`) which is making your question so hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think about what you want to remove (negative logic), think about what you want to print (positive):

```
$ echo 'FINDER=$FILE/$read\ammy.my' | grep -o '[$][[:alpha:]]*'
$FILE
$read
```

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ echo 'FINDER=$FILE/$read\ammy.my' | awk -v RS='[$][[:alpha:]]*' 'RT{o=o s RT; s=OFS} END{print o}'
$FILE $read
```

In both cases we just define the regexp for the strings we want to print ($ followed by alphabetic characters) and then print the matching strings (via `-o` for grep and collecting then printing all the RTs for awk).

Comment: Sorry to disturb Ed ! What if the variable is a combination of alphabet, alpha-numeric, alpha-character?  Example: 1) FINDER=$F12LE/$read\schcb.yy         2) FINDER=$F12_vcv\$read12/$rishab/ed.yu

Comment: No problem. You'd just change the regexp to suit. Sounds like you'd just change `alpha` to `alnum` character classes in the scripts I posted. I really think you could have figured that out for yourself though.

Comment: google is your friend - https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+regular+expression+combination+of+alphabet%2C+alpha-numeric%2C+alpha-character

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with perl:

```
echo 'FINDER=$FILE/$read\ammy.my' | perl -ne '@a=split(/[^\w\$]+/);print join(" ",grep{/^\$/}@a)."\n"'
$FILE $read
```

Explanation:

```
1. Split the string into an array, take nonletters and non-dollar-signs as the delimiter
2. join all elements which start with a dollar-sign and print them out
```